# ng2-datepicker is not working

Tags: angular, datepicker, webpack, datetimepicker

I am trying to use datepicker for my angular 2 app, but ng2-datepicker is not working

I have installed ng2-datepicker using npm:

`npm install ng2-datepicker --save`

Then imported DatePickerModule in app.modules.ts file:

`import { DatePickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';`

Then:

```
import { DatePickerOptions, DateModel } from 'ng2-datepicker';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    datePickerOptions: DatePickerOptions;
    date:DateModel;

constructor() {
        this.datePickerOptions = new DatePickerOptions();

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng2-datepicker [options]="datePickerOptions" name="date" [(ngModel)]="date"></ng2-datepicker>
```

I am not getting any error, but the datepicker is not showing.

Can anyone suggest datepicker module for angular 2 webpack project?

Comment: Are you using systemjs, or webpack?

Comment: I am using  webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sourcecode of ng-datepicker you will see that it exports an interface called DatepickerOptions (only two capital letters, not three). I believe this to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try z-index property to show it on top.

```
.ngx-datepicker-container[_ngcontent-c8] .ngx-datepicker-calendar- 
 container[_ngcontent-c8] {
 z-index: 999 !important;
 width: 100% !important;
}
```